# Can't get rails app to start on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a rails app to heroku, but keep getting the following error.  I'd have thought that managing the postgres gems would be something heroku would handle.

I've tried everything I can think of short of installing postgres on my local machine, which I'd need to do if I wanted to install the postgres gem.  There's also no gem called `activerecord-postgresql-adapter`... I'm guessing this is the standard adapter that comes with rails??

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
App failed to start

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:76:in `establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (no such file to load -- pg) (RuntimeError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:438:in `initialize_database'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /disk1/home/slugs/135415_c7f31f0_9f1f/mnt/config/environment.rb:9
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
 ... 14 levels...
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug because of different versions of `bundler` running on heroku and my machine.  I've switched to using the `.gems` dependency file and everything seems to be working.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm having this exact same error at the moment. Can you elaborate on this? What do you mean switched to using the .gems dependency file?

Comment: This is indeed old. .gems is very much deprecated, you should be using a Gemfile.

Comment: I am using a Gemfile, I'm running Rails 3.1. My error has now changed to something about the initializers. I'm going to post a new question. Never seen this before.

Comment: what is the `.gems` dependency?

Answer (score 7):

[Upgrade your Gemfile to Bundler 0.9](http://docs.heroku.com/gems#gem-bundler) and add the `pg` gem. Easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

Details on Heroku's bundler support are here: http://docs.heroku.com/bundler

Heroku requires you specify the 'pg' gem.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I've been working on the same thing for way too long now..

I realized I was using gem 'ps' instead of 'pg'

**>.<**

stupid postres gem!